# PHP Variable determine array function.. possible?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

The following code filters posts from the database by certain fields.

```
array('key' => 'telephone', 'value' => '0','compare' => '>')
```

Some other factors determine if there might be another array here. The problem is the code required to work that out will return a variable. `$filters;`

Is this possible

```
$filters = array('key' => 'mobile', 'value' => '0','compare' => '>')

array('key' => 'telephone', 'value' => '0','compare' => '>') . $filters
```

And if not how could this work.

CLARIFICATION

This is the structure that the function would require this to be in.

```
    'meta_query' => array(
array('key' => 'telephone', 'value' => '0','compare' => '>'),
array('key' => 'mobile', 'value' => '0','compare' => '>')
                        )
```

But we can't write it out like that as other factors determine what these queries will be. We have to get something like a variable containing the arrays to go inside the 'meta_query' array.

Comment: Do you want to merge two arrays or what?

Comment: You may be looking for [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge) or see also [array operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) as you can use the `+` sign to create a union of the 2 arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to pass it multiple filters in a single array.

Using `.` won't work because that is a string concatenation operation.

Use this for an array of arrays:

```
$filters[] = array('key' => 'mobile', 'value' => '0','compare' => '>');
$filters[] = array('key' => 'telephone', 'value' => '0','compare' => '>');
```

To get the right format for the function simply:

```
$meta['meta_query']=$filters;
```

Comment: Added some more info if you can help

Comment: Works for me with a few modifications... Good Stuff

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do `array_merge()`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php for details, but it works like:

```
$filters = array('key' => 'telephone', 'value' => '0','compare' => '>');
$filters = array_merge($filters, array('key' => 'telephone', 'value' => '0','compare' => '>'));
print_r($filters);
// array( 'key' => 'telephone', 'value' => '0', 'compare' => '>')
```